# jQuery div onclick to click an href inside the div

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<table class="products">
  <tr>
    <td>Product description probably goes here</td>
    <td><a href="#">more information</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To make it a bit sexier for Javascript-enabled browsers I've added this jQuery (1.3.2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table.products tr').click(function(){
    $(this).find('a').click();
    return false;
  });
});
```

But I think it gets into an infinite loop or something. Safari shows this:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size
>   exceeded. jquery.min.js:12

Can anyone please offer a workaround or better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that a lies within the tr. Ergo, when the a click() method is triggered, the event bubbles to the tr containing it, creating the recursive loop you mentioned. Rather than call `.find('a').click()`, have both `a` and `tr` use the same click method.

```
$('tr, a').click(function(){
   //dostuff
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I solved it with adding `e.stopPropagation();` to the a on click:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table.products tr').bind('click', function() {
    $(this).find('a').click();
    return false;
  });

  $('table.products tr a').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty late answer, but I found this to be a very short and simple solution:

```
$('ul li').bind('click', function() {
    location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: this is the only answer that worked for me, trying:
`$('#PARENT').each(function(){
  $(this).find("a").click();
  return false;
});
$('#PARENT a').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});`, the inside click wouldn't work, but this solution finally did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try to use `bind('click')` instead of `click()` shortcut, it worked for me in almost same case.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would `console.log($(this).find('a'))` and make sure it is the appropriate link.
Next, I believe the click event is not what you want on the `a` element. I think you just want: `var a = $(this).find('a'); if (a) document.location.href = a.attr('href');`

My JavaScript is pretty weak though : )

Answer (score 0):

mine was a list item in a dropdown so i wanted the event to keep bubbling so the dropdown would be closed. this is the solution i used:

```
$('div#outer').click(function (e) {
   if (e.target == e.currentTarget) // prevents bubbled events from triggering
      $($(e.currentTarget).children()[0]).trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table.products tr').click(function(e){
    e.stoPropagation(); // for stop the click action (event)
    $(this).find('a').click();
    return false;
  });
});
```